# will allah fgorgive me and make my mother`s heart?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, forgiveness, relationships, depression

Assalam o Alaikum
I`m here to tell my sins and ...... the problems I'm facing. I was in a haram relationship and my mom caught me last night talking to him this was my first time ... I was never like this I was a sweet, innocent girl. I want to repent of my sins. So my question is will my mother and Allah ever forgive me

Answer (score 0):

As salaamu alaikum never tell your sins publicly.

On the authority of Anas (may Allah be pleased with him), who said:

I heard prophet muhammadﷺ say: Allah the Almighty said:

"O son of Adam, as long as you call upon Me and put your hope in Me, I have forgiven you for what you have done and I do not mind. O son of Adam, if your sins were to reach the clouds of the sky and then you seek My forgiveness, I would forgive you. O son of Adam, if you were to come to Me with sins that are close to filling the earth and then you would meet Me without ascribing any partners with Me, I would certainly bring you forgiveness close to filling it." [Al-Tirmidhi] (Grade: Hasan)

Say, 0 Prophet, that Allah says, 1 "O My servants who have exceeded the limits against their souls! Do not lose hope in Allah's mercy, for Allah certainly forgives all sins. He is indeed the All-Forgiving, Most Merciful.
Az-Zumar (39) : 53

Show kindness and seek forgiveness from your mother, who you may have disappointed. Request her forgiveness gently and reassure her that you have also asked for forgiveness from Allah. Remember, you only have one mother, so treat her with respect. Listen to her without arguing if she yells, and continue to be kind even if she does not forgive you immediately. Pray for her forgiveness and strive to always be good to her.